# How to access WordPress site from another machine in same network

Tags: networking, wamp, wordpress

I created a WordPress web site & now I want to give access permission to other users in same network to view my web site. I used WAMP server & it is online. When I access it from another machine using the `http://192.168.0.4/wordpress` it displays only the text (not displaying any images and the effects).

I followed lot of instructions and none of them are working.

Comment: Please provide a little more info. For example, a snippet of code from the page source that isn't working like you expect, such as an image that should be loading but isn't.

Comment: the local ip address of the wamp server machine is 192.168.0.4. my machine is 192.168.0.29. so i want to view my website on wamp server in my machine (192.168.0.29) both are networked. i changed phpmyadmin config file as follows. but it also didnt work. options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews AllowOverride all order Deny, Allow Deny from all Allow from 127.0.0.1

Comment: @user3778844 I think the problem is your Wordpress configuration itself.  Make sure you aren't forcing any particular domain name/address in your WP configuration, or change it to your computer's internal IP address.

Comment: What does your "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site address (URL)" show in your wp-admin interface? WordPress uses these to make sure your URLs work properly. This is why you should never use something like WAMP or XAMPP for a production site or you configure your LAN (easiest to use the `hosts` file) to point a real domain name (obviously make sure it's a fake domain that no-one is likely to ever visit - e.g. `companytestsite.com`) to your test server IP address and configure your webserver to use name-based virtualhosts which will allow your server to respond to actual name-based requests.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue with MAMP. The resolution was adding the port number after the hostname in the URL. You might try something like this: `http://192.168.0.4:80/wordpress`